# Generate a 64-bit number (as a hex string)

Tags: php

I'm reading the android docs specifically http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID .

I'd like to emulate this function to generate an android_id value in PHP for use in a little 
test script. It seems all values are 16 characters long and alphanumeric. I want my value to be perfectly valid rather than just generating an alphanumeric 16 character string. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Based on Tom's contribution below can someone confirm that the code,

bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8));

would return a perfectly valid android_id

Comment: What do you mean by "valid?"

Comment: A valid output would be a 64 bit number that is converted to a hex string and then can converted back from hex to number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$id = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8));
```

It generates a hex representation of a 64 bit random number.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I figured that OP wants to emulate that?

Comment: No, he can already get that from the original function.  He wants the actual 64 bit number, not its hex representation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, that's dependent on a few factors; having a binary representation is the most portable.

Comment: OK, well I think I misread his question (or his not so clarifying comment).  I guess he wants an equivalent PHP function that does the same thing as the Android function does.  I haven't a clue why he might want that, but I've upvoted your answer accordingly.

Comment: I think this is the answer, can you confirm it does the same thing as the native android function posted by Tom below?

Comment: @RGibson1972 It achieves the same thing, but instead of converting a 64-bit random integer it converts an 8-byte random binary blob which is effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

A valid hex string contains just numbers and letters from A to F both inclusive. Example "014AEC092FA74D78".

Comment: He wants an actual number in a variable, not a string.  See the comments below the question.

Comment: lalborno's answer here is correct, if terse. Generate a random string containing only digits and the letters A through F and you have a perfectly valid hex number. Ensure that the string is no longer than 16 characters (4 bits per character), then it is a perfectly valid 64 bit number (which might be positive or negative).

Answer (score 2):

This might now be exactly what you're going for, but I wanted to post this to SO because I haven't been able to find this anywhere else from a quick search.
Below is the code from the SettingsProvider package that *actually* generates the ANDROID_ID for a device.

```
private boolean ensureAndroidIdIsSet() {
    final Cursor c = query(Settings.Secure.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { Settings.NameValueTable.VALUE },
            Settings.NameValueTable.NAME + "=?",
            new String[] { Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID }, null);
    try {
        final String value = c.moveToNext() ? c.getString(0) : null;
        if (value == null) {
            final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            final String newAndroidIdValue = Long.toHexString(random.nextLong());
            Log.d(TAG, "Generated and saved new ANDROID_ID [" + newAndroidIdValue + "]");
            final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Settings.NameValueTable.NAME, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            values.put(Settings.NameValueTable.VALUE, newAndroidIdValue);
            final Uri uri = insert(Settings.Secure.CONTENT_URI, values);
            if (uri == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Given this function, it could easily be emulated in PHP as Jack and others have pointed out. You're really just creating a 64 bit random number and storing it as a hexadecimal string. There's any number of ways to accomplish this, so I'll leave that part up to the reader.

Comment: This is great, I could not find this function anywhere. I guess I just need to find the equivalent PHP functions for Long.toHexString and SecureRandom.

Answer (score 1):

with PHP 7 can be used:

```
$id = bin2hex(random_bytes(8));
```

or
(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7 < 7.2.0, PECL mcrypt >= 1.0.0)

```
$id = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
```

an example of use:

```
function RandomToken($length = 32){
    if(!isset($length) || intval($length) <= 8 ){
      $length = 32;
    }
    if (function_exists('random_bytes')) {
        return bin2hex(random_bytes($length));
    }
    if (function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv')) {
        return bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
    } 
    if (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
        return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length));
    }
}
```

reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php